# Unity: Turn on one GameObject after the other with KeyPress

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 7 game objects or more. I want to run only one gameObject after the other. Starting with Gameobject 0 --> GameObject 1 --> GameObject 2. At the moment my script activates a new object each time <kbd>Space</kbd> is pressed, and the old ones are not deactivated.

Thanks for your help!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ToggleTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objects; 
    public int objCount = 0; 


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {

            objCount += 1;
            objects[objCount].SetActive(true); 
            
        }
      
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "plays all GameObjects together"? Are you saying they are all made active the first time you press space?

Comment: every time i press space an additional gameObject gets activated

Comment: Ah, see that would be good information to include in the question ;) I edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, try this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ToggleTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objects; 
    public int objCount = 0;
    private float smallDelay = 0.1f; 


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && smallDelay <= 0)
        {
            objCount += 1;
            objects[objCount].SetActive(true); 
            objects[objCount-1].SetActive(false);  // this is only if you want to deactivate the previous object.
            smallDelay = 0.1f;
        }
        smallDelay -= Time.DeltaTime;
      
    }
}
```

This is not a perfect code, but because your function's if statement is one the `Update()` method, I think it needs a little delay. You can also change the smallDelay to a bigger number.

**EDIT**

This is the answer on your comment:

```
if (objCount == objects.Length)
{
   objCount = 0;
   object[objCount].setActive(false);
   object[0].setActive(true);

}
```

add this in the if statement or somewhere else in the Update().

Comment: Without the delay it worked perfectly! Do you know how to restart the whole "counting" process after the last Game Object. That it begins again with Object 0?

Comment: Check the *Edit* on my post:

Comment: No it still stops after the last Object and does not start again in the play mode. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @unitybeginner I edited the answer again, does that work?

Comment: No...it still ends after the last object. And at the end i want to stop it with "Escape"

Comment: @unitybeginner Looks like activating only one object at time is solved isn't it?  Consider [accepting this answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) As for resetting to the beginning or ending with **Escape**, that would be a [different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) question, consider [posting it separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).